# Apex and salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am new to salesforce and apex as well. trying to use to understand both while working. I was wondering about following things

1. Is it possiable to run the Java code inside Salesforce, instead of Apex?
2. Is it possible to have packages in the Apex code so that I could enable the like wide classed together?
3. Is there any easy way to debug an Apex application on my local system? At present I am trying to put system.debug and execute it with Salesforce.
4. Can I configure the environment variable in the salesforce and use it in the Apex?

Thanks a lot for helping me out

Comment: In the future, please create a separate question for each question.

Comment: Thanks a lot but jaraybill but the documentation was not that clear. i will keep your advice in mind though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- You cannot run Java. Only Apex.
- Not sure what you mean by packages. Apex doesn't have anything like Java packages.
- There is no local debugging or local engine. Only runs in the cloud.
- For environment variables, custom settings are probably the closest analog.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for the response I will make sure that i will create different question next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't work with java directly in salesforce. But you can use Salesforce in your local java application and it sync your data with salesforce. I used it before and it's pretty easy, try to google it.

Answer (score 1):

you can also go with database.com + heroku/amazon if you want to develop with different language in salesforce platform

Answer (score 0):

Just started with Apex and Salesforce myself.  I realize this is an old post but here is my advice so far.  Use Install java 1.6, Helios eclipse, and then the force.com ide plugin. In that order.